# SQLite3 can't do addition in WHERE clause?

Tags: sqlite, where-clause, addition

I have the following simple query that I execute on a SQLite3 database:

```
SELECT AField,AnotherField FROM ATable WHERE AnIntField>strftime('%s');
```

This works fine and returns the expected result.

If I perform the slightly modified query:

```
SELECT AField,AnotherField FROM ATable WHERE AnIntField+86400>strftime('%s');
```

Then I don't get any results! This doesn't make any sense! I have tried putting brackets around `AnIntField+86400` but that doesn't help. And yes, the values of `AnIntField` are sufficiently larger than `strftime('%s')` that it won't return different results.

Is there any reason for this behaviour?

Comment: If you add `0` to it instead of `86400`, do you get results?

Comment: And, just for kicks, if you put parenthesis around each side of the `>`, does it make any difference?  It's out there, but I'm just curious if some orders of operations are getting misinterpreted.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a total guess but what happens if you wrap AnIntField+86400 in the SQLite3 equivalent of a cast ?

In TSQL you'd do something like this:

```
WHERE CAST(AnIntField + 86400 AS int) > strftime('%s')
```

My thought is that the AnIntField+val is coming out as an append rather than addition.

Actually, if cast doesn't work, try changing select to

```
SELECT AnIntField+86400 FROM ...
```

And see what it spits out.

Comment: Well it seems like the `CAST` works, but does anyone have an explanation why? When I did `SELECT AnIntField+86400` it displayed the correct value.

Comment: There's two reasons to me, either the addition is overflowing and the cast rounds it to a sane value, or the + operator is causing SQL to think you're appending the result of two strings, and the cast is returning an accurate integer value for comparison.